# Count corners in 2D numpy array or image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I need to find the number of corners (don't need the location of them, but would be preferred to verify) in the white area of this numpy array.

The white area is all 1's and everything else is 0.

I tried some if/else logic that kept being incomplete for edge cases, and I tried a Harris Corner detector from cv2 but it seems like its designed for denser (large number of pixel) images. In my case a corner can be small like

```
[0 0 0 0]

[0 1 1 1]

[0 1 1 1]
```

[image: plot of numpy image with plt]

EDIT:

image with corners circled here

[image: image with corners circled]

EDIT 2:
[what i see with plotting code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA4aM.png)

Comment: What is your definition of a "corner"?  What output would you expect for the example that you show?

Comment: Just to clarify: Can we define a corner as follows? The center pixel in any 3×3-pixel region in which (1) each pixel value is either 1 or 0, (2) exactly one corner has the same value as the center AND (3) the two edge pixels (and no other edge pixels) adjacent to that corner have the same value as the center.

Comment: @Howlium not necessarily, there can be a "concave" corner like [0,1,0] [ 1,1,0] [0,0,0]

Comment: The definition of corner implied by your "image with corners circled" is confusing: Is it that a corner location is never a pixel, but rather the intersection point between four pixels? EDIT: Based on your last comment, then it sounds like, that image notwithstanding, the definition might be "any 3x3 region in which the center is white and exactly two edges are white." Is that it? (Bottom line: I think a concrete definition will lead directly to a solution.)

Comment: @Howlium I suppose an intersection point between 4 pixels is true. Regarding the edit: not necessarily, [0,0,0] [0,1,1] [0,1,1] is a corner

Comment: Also, I verified in the image with corners circled. Yes, those are all the corners I want to identify.

Comment: please provide the data, not a plot of it. the image with corners circled is helpful for understanding though. -- use `cv::findContours` with some not-too-aggressive approximation. you might wanna work with a nearest-neighbor-*upscaled* image (factor 4 ought to be enough) because opencv will do "diagonal moves" instead of following pixel "edges" precisely.

Comment: If its easier, how can I find the total number of edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 80 corners on the white components of your image.

- threshold the image
- `findContours` with a gentle approximation mode (enough for *rectilinear* contours)
- count corners in contours

input image:

[image: im]

```py
(rv, thresholded) = cv.threshold(im, thresh=192, maxval=255, type=cv.THRESH_BINARY)
# imshow(thresholded)
```

thresholded:

[image: thresholded]

contours:

```py
(contours, hierarchy) = cv.findContours(thresholded, mode=cv.RETR_LIST, method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

draw some things:

```py
canvas = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.drawContours(canvas, contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(0,0,255))
for contour in contours:
    for corner in contour[:,0,:]:
        cv.circle(canvas, center=corner, radius=3, color=(0,0,255), lineType=cv.LINE_AA)
# imshow(canvas)
```

[image: canvas]

count some things:

```py
for contour in contours:
    print("+", len(contour))
print("=", sum(len(contour) for contour in contours), "in", len(contours))
```

```
+ 14
+ 8
+ 58
= 80 in 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is really close to what I need. Is there a way to get this to work on a small example like on a 60x60 array of 0s , filled with randomly placed 2x2 patches of 255's  ? Would I need to resize it up to get it to work?

Comment: do you _have_ such a picture? does it have right angles? can you show it? then you can try it on this code.

Comment: https://file.io/1NSwFgSyhWMC.  Here is an .npy to test with. I did a ``` panel_placement_grid = panel_placement_grid.astype(np.uint8) * 255 ``` on it to get it to work with your code

Comment: that would either require a `cv.resize(..., fx=4, fy=4, interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)` (not too expensive), or an entirely different approach from the one I presented.

Comment: I got it working, needed to do a np.repeat for the x and y axis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experimented using Hit and Miss transform [details on this site](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm)

Following is the key take-away:

> If the foreground and background pixels in the structuring element exactly match foreground and background pixels in the image, then the pixel underneath the origin of the structuring element is set to the foreground color. If it doesn't match, then that pixel is set to the background color.

**Illustration**

The image you have shared is smudged along the edges. So I had to create a different image for illustration:

[image]

There are 8 possible variations of corners that can be found:

The first 4 are white corners:

```
[0 0 0]     [0 1 1]     [1 1 0]     [0 0 0]
[0 1 1]     [0 1 1]     [1 1 0]     [1 1 0]
[0 1 1]     [0 0 0]     [0 0 0]     [1 1 0]
```

These 4 are black corners:

```
[1 1 1]     [1 0 0]     [0 0 1]     [1 1 1]
[1 0 0]     [1 0 0]     [0 0 1]     [0 0 1]
[1 0 0]     [1 1 1]     [1 1 1]     [0 0 1]
```

OpenCV has `cv2.morphologyEx` function to perform advanced morphological operations. Here we will use the same.

**Code:**

```
# Read image and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('image.png', 1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Create kernels to find 4 white corners
kernel1 = np.array((
        [[-1, -1, -1],
        [-1, 1, 1],
        [-1, 1, 1]]))
kernel2 = np.array((
        [[-1, -1, -1],
        [1, 1, -1],
        [1, 1, -1]]))
kernel3 = np.array((
        [[1, 1, -1],
        [1, 1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1]])) 
kernel4 = np.array((
        [[-1, 1, 1],
        [-1, 1, 1],
        [-1, -1, -1]])) 

# The next four kernels are created by multiplying existing ones with '-1'
# Storing all of them in a list 
kernels = [kernel1, kernel2, kernel3, kernel4, kernel1*-1, kernel2*-1, kernel3*-1, kernel4*-1]

# Create a mask (in black) with same image shape to store corner points
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)
mask_fin = mask.copy()

# Find corner points by performing morphology with each kernel and accumulate them to 'mask'
for kernel in kernels:
    out_image = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_HITMISS, kernel)
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(out_image, mask)

# Since image is in grayscale there are corner points always greater than 0
# For this image They are all greater than 10
mask_fin[mask > 10] = 255
```

Position of all corners in the image:

[image]

```
# Create copy of original image and assign colored value to corners found
img2 = img.copy()
img2[mask_fin == 255] = (50, 255, 50)
```

You will have to zoom the image to see them clearly.

[image]

**End Notes:**

If you look closely:

- There are ***false*** corners being found at the 4 corners of the image. The kernels that find black corners find them.
- Corners close to the white, gray and black regions are often missed out. And that's because those regions don't match any of the kernels

*(Please note the above is not the final solution but a step/direction towards a good one. Hope you find it helpful)*