# Finding contours of inner holes for images with multiple outer contours

Tags: python, opencv

We have multiple contours. Some are positive and some are negative (holes). Here is the code i'm using

```py
def get_corners(grid: np.ndarray, show=False):

    corners = set()
    hole_corners = set()

    # Filter using contour hierarchy
    cnts, hierarchy = cv.findContours(grid, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]

    hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
    for component in zip(cnts, hierarchy):
        currentContour = component[0]
        currentHierarchy = component[1]
        # x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(currentContour)
        # Has hole which means it is IN
        if currentHierarchy[2] < 0:
            for corner in currentContour[:, 0, :]:
                corner_coords = tuple(corner.tolist())
                hole_corners.add(corner_coords)
            # cv.putText(image, 'IN', (x,y-10), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,255,12), 2)
        # No child which means it is OUT
        elif currentHierarchy[3] < 0:
            for corner in currentContour[:, 0, :]:
                corner_coords = tuple(corner.tolist())
                corners.add(corner_coords)
```

the problem with it is that, when there is more than one positive contour, it doesn't work as expected. every positive contour > 1 gets counted as a hole. here is it displayed.

- Red: positive contours
- Green: negatives/holes

As you can see its not working as expected.

all counted as holes

[image: all counted as holes]

one counted correctly, rest mostly incorrectly

[image: one counted correctly, rest mostly incorrectly]

image with contours labelled correctly (ignore corner color here)

[image: image with contours labelled correctly (ignore corner color here)]

[Another failure case with islands with no child being counted as holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEBIz.png)

```
 hierarchy for this: [[ 1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 3  0  2 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1  1]
 [-1  1 -1 -1]]
```

Comment: previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876693/count-corners-in-2d-numpy-array-or-image

Comment: your wording is weird. are you talking about corners? "inner/outer contours" already has meaning, and it's NOT what you seem to show in your pictures.

Comment: I meant inner contours as the contour of a "hole". 

Added an image labeled with what I mean if that helps

Comment: ah, so the colors are to be ignored? you should have said so in the beginning. also, those pictures initially had no labeling at all. -- why are you even messing around at all? OpenCV's findContours has two modes that give you this info *explicitly* (RETR_CCOMP and RETR_TREE) in the hierarchy result and the order of points of a contour also *implicitly* designates what type it is (use contourArea and check the sign)

Comment: I think you need to review [what the docs say about the hierarchy data](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a). it's four numbers per contour, pointing to `(next, prev, child, parent)`. from that alone, you can only tell if a contour is top-level (positive) or a child (pos/neg unknown). you'd have to pointer-chase until you're at the root, to know how many levels deep the current contour is. or use RETR_CCOMP, where you don't have that issue, because all positive contours are said to be at the root.

Comment: your graphics look buggy. for one individual contour, you have drawn its corners to be multiple colors. that's broken, right?

Comment: RETR_CCOMP seems to be the info that I need, outer contours and inner hole contours. however its not working as expected by checking if currentHierarchy[2] < 0: then its a hole contour, elif currentHierarchy[2] > 0: then its outer contour

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#:~:text=So%20consider%20first,answer%20I%20got%3A I basically need the (1) and (2) hierarchy levels that they display in green here

Comment: The hierarchy you listed shows that 2 is a child of 1. Is that not the hole?

Comment: root contours have no parent. no parent means -1. holes have a parent. valid parents are >= 0. -- you seem confused about indexing. arrays start at 0. [3] stands for the fourth element, which is the parent index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. using RETR_CCOMP and checking for currentHierarchy[3] worked for me. Corners is a set with all corners of the outer contours, hole_corners is a set with all corners of the inner, or hole contours.

```py
(cnts, hierarchy) = cv.findContours(grid,mode=cv.RETR_CCOMP, method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS)

corners = set()
hole_corners = set()

# Filter using contour hierarchy

hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
for component in zip(cnts, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    (hnext, hprev, hchild, hparent) = currentHierarchy

    if hparent < 0:
        # Has no parent, which means it is not a hole
        for corner in currentContour[:, 0, :]:
            corner_coords = tuple(corner.tolist())
            corners.add(corner_coords)
    else:
        # Has a parent, which means it is a hole
        for corner in currentContour[:, 0, :]:
            corner_coords = tuple(corner.tolist())
            hole_corners.add(corner_coords)
```